# Can I direct ffmpeg to a folder to do work using SET PATH?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some "MXF-type" media (various media files in a containing folder) As long as I have cmd line set to the media folder it works but if I want to run from C: and point to the media directory using explicit SET PATH it won't run ffmpeg. I don't know why. What is wrong with the way I am expecting SET PATH to work?

```
C:\Users\MYNAME>SET PATH=%PATH%;"H:\2017\PeterMc\camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).vmf\" ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 0 -i camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -write_tmcd 1 camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mp4
```

While the following example works you can see that cmd must be in the media folder path.

```
H:\2017\Peter Mc\camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).vmf> ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 0 -i camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mov -map 0:v -map 0:a -write_tmcd 1 camb_LungDoctor_730_1403(1).mp4
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with path. ffmpeg will look in the current directory as a fallback since it can't parse the Unix path in the drefs.

Comment: Oh I see. Ok thanks... defeated I am then, lots of change path in my future I suppose. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use a batch file which navigates to the media path and then after the operation does `cd -` to go back.